# How to print arguments' list in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to print arguments' list in full or in parts in JavaScript?

**Example:**
from within the function `my_assert(a!=b)` I'd like to print `a!=b`, or even `2!=3` for a particular function call.

Answer (score 3):

you can't. `a!=b` is executed first and only the result of this (`true` or `false`) is given to your function so you don't have a chance to get back `a!=b` or `2!=3`.

Comment: why does this answer get 3 votes when it doesn't actually address the question asked and instead points out a syntax error in a question that doesn't even have all that much syntax?  Granted, it's a useful hint, but I fail to see how it's worth voting up as the "best" answer since it's not actually one at all.

Comment: @GeniaS. ... it directly addresses the concerns of the OP... they wanted to get the values from within var's a and b, not the passed in value. Subtle change in reading the question....

Answer (score 3):

```
 console.log (arguments)
```

will print the arguments given to the function, but in your case, all your function sees is a boolean, because `a != b` will be evaluated first, and only the result passed as a parameter in the function call.

Answer (score 1):

umm... here, I'll google it for you :)
http://www.seifi.org/javascript/javascript-arguments.html

As some others pointed out, passing in a test (a != b) will only get you a boolean value (true|false) as your argument. But if you call myAssert(a,b), you can then evaluate the arguments and test their equality, as well as print their values, following the advice in the link I pasted.

Comment: I google'd it and ended up here... that's not so bad, is it? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
my_assert = (test) ->
    str = my_assert.caller.toString()
    match = /return my_assert\((.*)\)/.exec str
    console.log match[1], test

a = '1'
b = '2'
do -> my_assert(a!=b)
do -> my_assert(b!=a)


> a !== b true
> b !== a true
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7qRN/

The only caveat is you have to call your `my_assert` calls from separate anonymous functions in order to be able to reliably get the source code of the assertion call.

In CoffeeScript its not so bad using the `do ->` notation.

In JS this is: `(function(){my_assert(a!=b)})();`.

You could pass in the test as a function like so:

`my_assert -> a!=b`

`my_assert(function(){a!=b});`

Answer (score 1):

```
//
// A variation on vaughan's answer, from Oct 1 '13
// Includes simple unit test to debug the regex for multiline assert expressions
// Use console.error and/or 'throw new Error' depending how you handle errors
//
function test_assert() {
  try {
    (function () { assert(3 === 'a') })();

    (function () {
      assert('foo' !== 'bar')
    })();

    (function () {
      assert('foo' ===
        'bar')
    })();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.stack)
  }
} // test_assert

function assert(expression) {
  if (!expression) {
    let caller = assert.caller.toString()
    let test = caller.match(/assert[^]*\)/)
    //throw new Error(test[0] + ' failed');
    console.error('%s failed', test[0])
  }

} // assert

/////////////////////////////////
// Here's a simple assert()

function assert2(condition, message) {
  if (!condition) {
    console.error('assert (%s) failed: "%s"', condition, message)
    throw new Error("Assertion failed: " + message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. When you have the following line:

```
my_assert(a!=b);
```

The expression `a!=b` will first be evaluated and its result will be passed to `my_assert`.

Assuming your `my_assert()` function is used specifically for your own testing and you can control how it works and what you pass into it you could do something like this:

```
my_assert(a!=b, "a!=b");
```

I.e., pass an extra parameter to the function with a string representation of what is being tested. Obviously that doesn't stop you accidentally saying `my_assert(a!=b, "a==b");`, and it's clunky, but I can't think of another way to do it.

Comment: Or rather `assertNotEqual(a,b)`

Comment: Good point @Thilo, though that still won't let the assert function know the names of the variables passed in. Obviously in my answer I was thinking more of an `assertIsTrue(anyexpression)`.